# How random is glm::sphericalRand()? Some angles seem more common than others

Tags: c++, rendering, glm-math, raytracing

I am following along with [Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html), where Lambert's cosine law is simulated by picking a random point on the surface of a unit sphere and sending a ray in that direction.

The author uses a simple rejection method for generating a random point on the sphere. Since I was already working with GLM, I thought I would be clever and use `glm::sphericalRand()` instead of doing the work myself. I then decided to see how uniformly distributed the points actually were, and plotted their angles with respect to a normal facing in the y direction:

```cpp
float buckets[200] = {};

std::srand(time(0)); // Give glm a new seed

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    const glm::vec3 normal = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    const glm::vec3 randomVector = glm::sphericalRand(1.0f); // Implicitly normalized (sphere radius of 1)
    const float dot = glm::dot(randomVector, normal);

    const int bucket = 100 + dot * 100; // Pick a bucket in the range [0, 199]

    buckets[bucket]++;
}
```

I generate 10.000.000 random vectors on a unit sphere using `glm::sphericalRand()`, and take their dot product with the normal. I then increment the bucket corresponding to the value of their dot product.

Each bucket represents the number of vectors within a certain range of angles to the normal. Vectors with a dot product in the range of [-1, -0.99> go in bucket 0, [-0.99, -0.98> in bucket 1, etc.

I expected all angles (buckets) to be chosen approximately equally often. However, this did not seem to be the case. I plotted the number of entries in each bucket below.

[image]

Evidently, every bucket has approximately 50.000 entries, which makes sense with 10.000.000 total samples and 200 buckets. However, bucket 99 (corresponding to a dot product of 0) shows a clear dip with approximately half as many samples.

I decided to make my own function to generate a random point on a sphere using [this stackexchange comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585996):

```cpp
glm::vec3 sphericalRand(float radius = 1.0f) {
    glm::vec3 randomVec = glm::vec3(glm::gaussRand(0.0f, 1.0f), glm::gaussRand(0.0f, 1.0f), glm::gaussRand(0.0f, 1.0f));
    return glm::normalize(randomVec) * radius;
}
```

Plotting this yielded the following results:

[image]

The dip close to a dot product of 0 is less pronounced (though definitely still there). However, some other phenomenon now shows up: there are generally fewer samples with *positive* dot products (bucket 100 through 199) than there samples with *negative* dot products (buckets 0 through 99).

Is this a result of how `std::rand()` works (which I believe is what GLM uses under the hood)? Or is something else going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer but back in 2017 while working on my thesis I noticed that *sphericalRand* was exclusive in the range it generated for theta and phi.

[image: Sphere with 1m generated points, clearly missing slices.]

It was something that allegedly got fixed, after I opened an issue (the issues got nuked). https://github.com/g-truc/glm/pull/708/files

However I had also mentioned that *linearRand* was also exclusive, which *sphericalRand* uses.

My solution at the time was to just use `std::rand()` and do it myself.

```
float theta = 2 * PI * ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
float phi = acos(2.0f * ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) - 1.0f);
glm::vec3 point = sphereToCartesian(rho, theta, phi);
```